# A non constant complex valued function with zero derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

I need an example of a non constant complex valued function whose derivative is zero at every point in in the complex plane.

Answer (score 3):

A complex valued function on a connected set with derivative $0$ is a constant. (Refer Stein - Shakarachi Complex analysis Chapter 1 for proof.)

If the function is defined on disconnected regions then its derivative is zero need not imply function is constant.

For example take $f$ to be $1$ on $|z|<1$ and $2$ on $|z-3|<1$. Then $f$ is non-constant but $f'(z)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If by derivative you mean:
$$
\frac{df(z)}{dz} = 0,
$$

then simply take $f(z)=\bar z$.

Comment: This function is not differentiable anywhere.

Comment: @Anirban So you mean holomorphic?

Comment: No. Not holomorphic or analytic. The definition of derivative is right. But the function you have given is not differentiable at any point.

Comment: @Anirban Wait. What is your definition of "complex-differentiable", if it is not "holomorphic"? I need to know what you exactly mean.

Comment: This is the same as we define in real analysis.

Comment: @Anirban There are many ways of generalizing it to complex functions. What do you mean *exactly*? You are asking for quite a subtle counterexample (if it exists). So we need to be extra-clear.

Comment: @geodude What definition of differentiable does you answer assume?

Comment: @fgp in my case, $\Bbb{R}^2$ differentiability. And I defined $d/dz$ as $d/dx -i d/dy$. It is the only notion that I could come up with, which could be less strict than holomorphy.

Comment: @geodude What does that mean? In $\mathbb{R}^2$ the differential is a $2\times 2$ matrix. How exactly do you map that to a complex number?

Comment: @fgp You map that into *two* complex numbers: $df/dz$ and $df/d\bar z$. The second is zero if and only if the $f$ is holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

A function  with zero derivative (anywhere) is always constant.

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ a function with zero derivative at any $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$.

We will write $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and $z_0=x_0+iy_0$.

So the derivative exists and $f'(z_0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(z_0+\Delta z)-f(z_0)}{\Delta z_0}$, and from its existence we conclude $f'(z_0)=\lim_{\Delta z\to0}\frac{f(z_0+\Delta x)-f(z_0)}{\Delta x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)=0$ and...

$f'(z_0)=\lim_{\Delta z\to0}\frac{f(z_0+i\Delta y)-f(z_0)}{i\Delta y}=-i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)=0$

Thus for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$,  $0=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ so $u:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is constant.

Moreover $0=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ so $v:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is constant.

Hence $u+iv=f$ is constant.

I think it holds ...